# Restoring an iPod from just copied files

Tags: backup, itunes, ipod

I had a HFS+ formatted iPod and a Windows PC. I used a HFS+ driver to copy everything to my Windows partion, and then formatted the iPod for Windows.

All the files in the iPod directory are strangely named. Is there a way to restore it to how it was so the songs and playlists will be recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the mp3 / m4a files into iTunes will recreate the music dircetory structure using the ID3 tags embedded in the files.

As for any other content you may have, well that's anyone's guess.

Comment: I can't even find the directory containing music? Should I delete everything except the music and just let it recreate everything? What about photos?

Comment: By default the content folder is hidden.  On my iPod Classic 160Gig it's located in \iPod_Control\Music\F[xx]\[xxx].mp3